# Reading POST data with nginx and Perl FastCGI

Tags: perl, nginx, fastcgi

I am setting up a website with nginx and need to let it run some perl programs, so I installed FastCGI and have it all set up. I added this to my site's configuration:

```
location ~ \.pl$ {
    gzip off;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
    fastcgi_index index.pl;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /[...]/www$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING     $query_string;
}
```

I then wrote a test.pl program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
print "Body here ";
print $#ARGV;
```

And I do get the result as "Body here -1". So the perl program is correctly running. Now the only issue I have is that, for the life of me, I can't find how to read in POST data. If that's tricky, I also can't find out how to read in the GET URL parameters. Either would be sufficient for me.

Comment: You can `use CGI`, but in most cases you want a real framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was simpler than it would have seemed. Below is the perl script I used.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use CGI;

print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";

my $q = CGI->new;
print "Your name is";
print $q->param("name");
```

And that's it. It's not specific to nginx at all.

Comment: Right, the whole point of CGI is that it is a platform-independent interface. But these days it's highly recommended that you use a full-features web framework that abstracts these details for you. (These days I like [Mojolicious](http://metacpan.org/module/Mojolicious).) It has a layer that can interface with nginx via Plack.

Comment: btw, no need for plack with mojolicious + nginx. In fact, for the really cool real-time features you don't want it. See [this](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Nginx) for more.